# PHP $_POST data to variable

Tags: php, variables, post

im editing some code for a client but i am stuck on a piece of code

```
<?php
include("sample/model.php");

if(!empty($username) && !empty($pass)){
    $data = aut($username,$pass,$database);

?>

    <form id="login"  action="index.php" method="post">
      <label>User</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" id="req" placeholder="User">
      <label>Password:</label>
      <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="Password">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter">
    </form>
```

As you can see the form post to it self, how is the post data transform to a variable, there is no function in the included file that does this and no other relevant code in index.php.
Hope someone can help on this.
Thanks in advanced!

Comment: what kind of a question is this? how are we suppose to find out what `aut()` does? use your editor -> find in files -> search for `aut(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If [`register_globals`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Register_globals) is on then data passed to a PHP script via cookies or GET and POST requests to be made available as global variables in the script.

There are [negative security ramifications for doing this](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) which is why this feature has been deprecated and then removed in PHP 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly. Try this out:

```
include("sample/model.php");
// $database <-- not really sure where you're getting that
$username = ( isset($_POST["username"]) ? $_POST["username"] : 'Not Found'); 
$pass = ( isset($_POST["pass"]) ? $_POST["pass"] : 'Not Found');
$data = aut($username,$pass,$database);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you're asking. You'd be defining a boolean, or you can turn $username into a variable and check if it's set in the actual if statement, but both will result in the same thing.

```
<?php
include("sample/model.php");
$username = isset($_POST['username'];
$pass = isset($_POST['pass'];
$pass_data = $_POST['pass'];
$user_data = $_POST['username'];
if(isset( && ){
    $data = aut($user_data,$pass_data,$database);

?>
```